# Codeigniter - Bonfire - Error 520 on user edit

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I have a problem with a codeigniter/bonfire installation, when I try to modify one of the users I get a 520 Error, and when I go back, the entire site returns 520 Errors. This happens 95% of the time (I've tested 20 times, working only the first time).

The problem is, as soon as I hit the save button in the user edit area I got the error, then as O try to load other pages the site shows the 530 Error again, until I clear everything (Cache, Sessions, Saved Passwrods) and load the site again.

The weird thing is that the information gets saved on the database, when I load it again the system shows the changes I've made.

I asked some fellow developers here at the company and they had the same issue.

System Info:

Bonfire Version: v0.7.3

CodeIgniter Version: 2.2.2

PHP Version: 5.4.43

I've that the problem only happens when I modify one user, save the info and then modify it again without leaving the current page. If I go back, and come back again to the user edit page it works without problems.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the error log? You haven't given us much to work off.

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to mention, the logs are empty right now (I have error log activated).  Also I have new info and I've added it to the question.